# Usar funciones para llenar una matriz

Tags: c++, funciones, matrices

se me presenta el siguiente problema: Realizar una función llamada ceros, que toma como parámetro una matriz de 3x4 de números enteros y no devuelve nada.  Debe rellenar con ceros la matriz de 3x4 que recibe como parámetro. De la misma manera, Realizar una función llamada mostrar, que toma como parámetro una matriz de 3x4 de números enteros y no devuelve nada.  Debe mostrar el contenido de las celdas de la matriz en pantalla.

He hecho todo el código bien pero por alguna razón no me compila. Si alguien pudiera indicarme que esta mal se lo agradecería mucho.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void ceros(int);
void mostrar(int);
int i, j, m[3][4];
main ()
{
    ceros(m[3][4]);
    mostrar(m[3][4]);
    getch();
}
void ceros (int m[3][4])
{
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            m[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            printf (" %d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
void mostrar (int m[3][4])
{
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            printf ("\n Digite los elementos de la matriz: ");
            scanf ("%d", &m[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            printf (" %d", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes declarar en el encabezado de las funciones ceros y mostrar con los parámetros correctos. A dichas funciones le quieres pasar la matriz de enteros pero las declaras como int solamente.
Debes declararlas así:
    void ceros(int[][]);
    void mostrar(int[][]);